# How to print out matached string with perlre?

Tags: regex, perl

Perlre (Perl Regular Expression) is used for searching / replacing complex XML structure, e.g.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="[a-z0-9\-]+" ac:name="gadget" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="preferences">.*?selectedIssueKey=([A-Z\-0-9]+).*?(<\/ac:parameter>)<ac:parameter ac:name="url">https:\/\/rcrs.rbinternational.corp\/issue\/rest\/gadgets\/1.0\/g\/com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:greenhopper-card-view-gadget\/gadgets\/greenhopper-card-view.xml<\/ac:parameter>.*?(<\/ac:structured-macro>)/<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="server">RCRS Issue Tracking<\/ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="columns">key,type,assignee,status,nwu model developer,nwu model reviewer,nwu model owner,nwu head rr\/b2\/cro,ho validation owner,ho pi\/micro country manager,ho responsible signee<\/ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="maximumIssues">20<\/ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="jqlQuery">key = \1 <\/ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="serverId">d64129aa-b1e8-3584-8953-2bd89c3e515c<\/ac:parameter><\/ac:structured-macro>/igs' macro
```

Currently the search pattern does not match as expected. Obviously the search patterns spans more string than expected. Is there a possibility to print out each matched string for debugging purpose?

Comment: Use an XML parser for parsing XML. `regex` is a poor tool for this job. Post an XML snippet and what you're trying to extract, and we can give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on debugging for `regex` with `use re 'debug';`.  However that would be the wrong approach to take. Your problem here isn't your regex is wrong, it's that `regex` is fundamentally the wrong tool for `XML` parsing. (And leaving aside that - your line is just too long to be sensible to use inline like that!)

Given your example - it looks like you're trying to extract a single value (selectedIssueKey) and insert it into a new blob of XML.

This is done much easier by a parser, such as [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm). I can't give you a precise example, because I would need to see your XML structure (or at least a subset without the wildcards).

But something like this can be used for extracting a value from some XML:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA );
my $selectedIssueKey = $twig -> findnodes ( '//ac:parameter/pref', 0) -> att('selectedIssueKey');
print $selectedIssueKey;
```

Extracts the value of an attribute 'selectedIssueKey' from:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="test" ac:name="gadget" ac:schema-version="1">
  <ac:parameter ac:name="preferences">
      <pref selectedIssueKey="anothertest" />
  </ac:parameter>
  <ac:parameter ac:name="url">https://rcrs.rbinternational.corp/issue/rest/gadgets/1.0/g/com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:greenhopper-card-view-gadget/gadgets/greenhopper-card-view.xml</ac:parameter>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

`XML::Twig` also lets you cut and paste, so you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' ) ->  parsefile 'sample.xml' );
my $selectedIssueKey = $twig -> findnodes ( '//ac:parameter/pref', 0) -> att('selectedIssueKey');
print "Found key of: $selectedIssueKey\n";

my $ac_structured_macro = $twig -> findnodes ( '//ac:structured-macro',0 ); 

my $new_macro = $twig -> root -> insert_new_elt( 'last_child', 'ac:structured-macro', {  "ac:name" => "jira", "ac:schema-version"=> "1" } );
$new_macro -> insert_new_elt('last_child', 'ac:parameter', { 'ac:name' => 'server' }, "RCRS ISSUE Tracking" );
$new_macro -> insert_new_elt('last_child', 'ac:parameter', { 'ac:name' => 'columns' }, "key,type,assignee,status,etc" );
$new_macro -> insert_new_elt('last_child', 'ac:parameter', { 'ac:name' => 'maximumIssues' }, "20" );
$new_macro -> insert_new_elt('last_child', 'ac:parameter', { 'ac:name' => 'jqlQuery' }, "key = $selectedIssueKey" );
$new_macro -> insert_new_elt('last_child', 'ac:parameter', { 'ac:name' => 'serverId' }, "d64129aa-b1e8-3584-8953-2bd89c3e515c" );


$ac_structured_macro -> delete; 
$twig -> print;
```

(It's probably easier to use a whole XML snippet for this though, and just replace the bits yo uwant).

Answer (score 1):

```
use re 'debug'
```

To debug you regex, read more about it here http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#%27debug%27-mode

Answer (score 1):

Use a CPAN module for this. May save you some headache.

But if you still want to use regex for the job, I'd suggest you expand the regex in a script and step through it using the debugger like mentioned above.